# SAT formula for connected graphs on the grid

Tags: satisfiability, square-grid, connected

In the answer to an earlier question "[SAT algorithm for determining if a graph is disjoint](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/111411/4287)" a formula is constructed that is satisfiable iff a given graph is connected.

The formula uses a lot of variables, as basically a breadth first search is performed and the variables code the number of steps needed to reach a vertex from the origin (which is an arbitrary, fixed vertex).

Here I want to specialise this to graphs that are actually embedded on the grid. The vertices are the points of a $m\times n$ grid, and edges are only between the east/north/west/south neighbours in the grid.

Is there a solution that is more variable-efficient, using the restricted topology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new answer, https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/142450/755, to that question.  Applied to your situation, my solution uses $O(mn \lg(m+n))$ variables, which is asymptotically better than Yuval's algorithm (which uses $mn(m+n)$ variables).

Comment: Thanks. Now I had to solve a dilemma: I decided to vote on the "real answer", at the earlier question.

Comment: But, as I could not award the same bounty for two different answers, a bounty goes here.